# How to read IE page source using jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, ui-automation

I have a button in my html page. On click of this button i have to invoke the url of a web page and read the source page, pick the value of html tags and print those values in my web page. I need to use javascript or jquery for this and IE, firefox browsers. Any help with a sample in appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a HTTP request to that page which you want to read - the response will contain the page's HTML code which you can parse using jQuery.

```
jQuery.get("page.html", function(data){});
```

The method above might help you. It's well documented in the http://api.jquery.com documentation.

Just a heads up: the request will be subject to the Same Origin Policy which means that you might be restricted by the browser how your script can interact with another origin.